# How to Split a html page in to A4 size pages in angular 6?

Tags: jquery, css, typescript, angular6

I'm trying to print a report with dynamically generated content every time. Page splitting using CSS is not working properly with dynamic content.so I'm looking for a solution that will help the dynamic content to seat properly within the size of A4. if exceeds it should go sit in the next page like MSWord.

I've tried JSPDF and CSS which didn't work properly content overlapping problem was present.

```
  snipMe(element) {
    this.time++;
    this.page_count++;
    if (this.page_count > this.max_pages) {
      return;
    }

    let long = $(element)[0].scrollHeight - Math.ceil($(element).innerHeight());

    const ScrollHeight = $(element)[0].scrollHeight;
    const InnerHeight = Math.ceil($(element).innerHeight());
    const HiddenContentHeight = $(element)[0].scrollHeight - Math.ceil($(element).innerHeight());
    const children = $(element).children().toArray();
    const removed = [];
    while (long > 0 && children.length > 0) {
      const child = children.pop();
      $(child).detach();
      removed.unshift(child);
      long = $(element)[0].scrollHeight - Math.ceil($(element).innerHeight());
    }

    if (removed.length > 0) {
      const a4 = $('<div class= "cls' + removed.length + ' A4"></div>');
      const mycontent = '<pre>hello im a pre tag</pre>';
      // a4.append(mycontent);
      a4.append(removed);
      a4.css({
        'background': 'white',
        'width': '21cm',
        'height': '29.7cm',
        'display': 'block',
        'margin': '0 auto',
        'padding': '10px 25px',
        'margin-bottom': '0.5cm',
        'box-shadow': '0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        // 'overflow-y': 'scroll',
        'box-sizing': 'border - box',
        'font-size': '12pt'
      });
      $(element).after(a4);
      this.snipMe(a4[0]);
    }
  }
```

I'm using the above jquery code for now.